# Copy and paste with a WPF dataGrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, copy-paste

I am working with WPF and Visual Basic. I'm trying to have a button which allows to copy from the DataGrid that I have. Nothing I do seems to allow me to access the selected data, and to use the alternative of just triggering a copy event on the DataGrid I don't know how. Here is one such failing code example:

```
Private Sub btnFECopy_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnFECopy.Click
    Dim text As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each row As DataGridCellInfo In dgFileEditorWindow.SelectedCells
        For Each cell As System.Data.DataRowView In row.Item
            If Not text.Equals("") Then
                text.Append(";")
            End If
            text = text.Append(cell.ToString)
            'MsgBox(cell.Column.DisplayIndex)
            'MsgBox(dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item))
        Next
    Next

    'Nothing text.Append(dgFileEditorWindow.CurrentCell.Item.ToString())

    'Nothing Console.WriteLine(dgFileEditorWindow.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber & " " & dgFileEditorWindow.CurrentCell.RowNumber)

        Clipboard.SetText(text.ToString())
End Sub
```

Any Hints?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example:

I created a datagridview with a button.

The button loops through the selected datagridviewcells

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim text As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each dgvr As DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
        If Not Text.Equals("") Then
            Text.Append(";")
        End If

    Next

    Clipboard.SetText(text.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks much for the reply. Is this for WPF? I get DataGridViewCell is not defined and at the moment I am using a dataGrid not a dataGridView.